# Pandas TimeGrouper issue - Typeerror on "time" index

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to extract the timestamps from my inbox in order to generate some statistics with Pandas. My code grabs up to 1000 emails, and stores the timestamps in a list. I then pass the list to pd.DataFrame, which gives me a dataframe with a column of type "time".

I want to use groupby and TimeGrouper in order to plot the number of emails by weekday, time of day, etc., so I set my timestamp column as the index, but I get a TypeError: "Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'". I have tried using to_datetime, but that generates another TypeError: object of type 'time' has no len(). From what I can tell, df[0] is already a datetime object, so why does it throw an error when trying to use TimeGrouper?

```
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)                              
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
timesReceived = [message.SentOn]

for i in range(1000): 
    try:
        message = messages.GetPrevious()
        timesReceived.append(message.SentOn)
    except(AttributeError):
        break 

df = pd.DataFrame(timesReceived);
df.set_index(df[0],inplace=True)
grouped = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M'))


TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'
```

Edit: Adding df.info() and df.head()

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 150 entries, 04/01/16 09:37:07 to 02/11/16 17:40:56
Data columns (total 1 columns):
0    150 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 2.3+ KB

df.head()
    0
0   
04/01/16 09:37:07   04/01/16 09:37:07
04/01/16 04:34:30   04/01/16 04:34:30
04/01/16 03:02:14   04/01/16 03:02:14
04/01/16 02:15:12   04/01/16 02:15:12
04/01/16 00:16:27   04/01/16 00:16:27
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the output of `df.info()` and `df.head()`?

Comment: Sure, I've edited my post to include it. Thanks

Comment: `Index: 150 entries` suggests your `index` columns needs to be converted to `datetime` using `pd.to_datetime()` first. `df[0]` may look like `datetime` but needs type conversion, try `df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0], format='%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')` before setting to index.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks a lot. The following seems to have done the trick (changed the format string slightly):
`df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0], format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')`

`df.info()` now returns `DatetimeIndex: 150 entries`. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: alright, posted as answer so can mark this as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Index: 150 entries` suggests your `index` column needs to be converted to `datetime` using `pd.to_datetime()` first.

`df[0]` may look like `datetime` but needs type conversion, try

```
df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

before setting to index.