# Pandas groupby hour of the day to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, dataframe

I have a `pandas` data frame as follows:

```
date                | Item   | count
------------------------------------
2016-12-06 10:45:08 |  Item1 |  60
2016-12-06 10:45:08 |  Item2 |  145
2016-12-06 09:45:00 |  Item1 |  60
2016-12-06 09:44:54 |  Item3 |  600
2016-12-06 09:44:48 |  Item4 |  15
2016-12-06 11:45:08 |  Item1 |  60
2016-12-06 10:45:08 |  Item2 |  14
2016-11-06 09:45:00 |  Item1 |  62
2016-11-06 09:44:54 |  Item3 |  6
2016-11-06 09:44:48 |  Item4 |  15
```

I am trying to groupby the Items by let's say hour of the day (or later just day) to know the following statistics:
 list of items sold per day, such as:

- On `2016-12-06`, from `09:00:00` to `10:00:00`, Item1 , Item3 and Item4  were sold; and so on.
- On `2016-12-06`, Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4 (unique items) were sold.

While I am far away from fetching these statistics, I am stuck with grouping by time.
Initially, the `print df.dtypes` showed

```
date    object
Item    object
count   int64
dtype: object
```

So, I used the following line of code to convert the date column to a pandas date object.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

and now, `print df.dtypes` yields:

```
date    datetime64[ns]
Item    object
count   int64
dtype: object
```

However, when I try to groupby the `date` column using `TimeGrouper` by executing the following lines of code

```
from pandas.tseries.resample import TimeGrouper 
print df.groupby([df['date'],pd.TimeGrouper(freq='Min')])
```

I get the following `TypeError`. As per the suggestions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30857680/pandas-resampling-error-only-valid-with-datetimeindex-or-periodindex) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358730/pandas-timegrouper-issue-typeerror-on-time-index), converting using pd.to_datetime  should have resolved this issue.

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'
```

I have no clue how to solve this issue to proceed to the statistics I am looking for. Any tips on resolving this error and using TimeGrouper to seek the statistics preferably in a dictionary format (or anything that makes more sense) would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `groupby` by `numpy array` - datetimes with removed `minutes` and `seconds`:

```
print (df['date'].values.astype('<M8[h]'))
['2016-12-06T10' '2016-12-06T10' '2016-12-06T09' '2016-12-06T09'
 '2016-12-06T09' '2016-12-06T11' '2016-12-06T10' '2016-11-06T09'
 '2016-11-06T09' '2016-11-06T09']

print (df.groupby(df['date'].values.astype('<M8[h]')).Item.unique())
2016-11-06 09:00:00    [Item1, Item3, Item4]
2016-12-06 09:00:00    [Item1, Item3, Item4]
2016-12-06 10:00:00           [Item1, Item2]
2016-12-06 11:00:00                  [Item1]
Name: Item, dtype: object

print (df.groupby(df['date'].values.astype('<M8[h]')).Item
         .apply(lambda x: x.unique().tolist()).to_dict())
{Timestamp('2016-11-06 09:00:00'): ['Item1', 'Item3', 'Item4'], 
 Timestamp('2016-12-06 09:00:00'): ['Item1', 'Item3', 'Item4'], 
 Timestamp('2016-12-06 10:00:00'): ['Item1', 'Item2'], 
 Timestamp('2016-12-06 11:00:00'): ['Item1']}
```

---

```
print (df.groupby(df['date'].values.astype('<M8[D]')).Item
         .apply(lambda x: x.unique().tolist()).to_dict())
{Timestamp('2016-11-06 00:00:00'): ['Item1', 'Item3', 'Item4'], 
 Timestamp('2016-12-06 00:00:00'): ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4']}
```

Thank you [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998042/pandas-groupby-hour-of-the-day-to-dictionary/41998146?noredirect=1#comment71177369_41998146) for suggestion use [`round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.round.html):

```
print (df.groupby(df['date'].dt.round('h')).Item
         .apply(lambda x: x.unique().tolist()).to_dict())

{Timestamp('2016-11-06 10:00:00'): ['Item1', 'Item3', 'Item4'], 
 Timestamp('2016-12-06 12:00:00'): ['Item1'], 
 Timestamp('2016-12-06 10:00:00'): ['Item1', 'Item3', 'Item4'], 
 Timestamp('2016-12-06 11:00:00'): ['Item1', 'Item2']}

print (df.groupby(df['date'].dt.round('d')).Item
         .apply(lambda x: x.unique().tolist()).to_dict())
{Timestamp('2016-11-06 00:00:00'): ['Item1', 'Item3', 'Item4'], 
 Timestamp('2016-12-06 00:00:00'): ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4']}
```

Comment: btw, I really like that.  I'll remember it for later.

Comment: more idiomatic to use .round('min')

Comment: .dt.round('min') it's a method on the accessor

Answer (score 3):

```
sold = df.set_index('date').Item.resample('H').agg({'Sold': 'unique'})
sold[sold.Sold.str.len() > 0]

                                      Sold
date                                      
2016-11-06 09:00:00  [Item4, Item3, Item1]
2016-12-06 09:00:00  [Item4, Item3, Item1]
2016-12-06 10:00:00         [Item1, Item2]
2016-12-06 11:00:00                [Item1]
```